# Dynamic Operators in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Let's say I have the following table tbl_Rules:

```
RuleID  NameOperator     NameValues   TypeOperator   TypeValue    
1       NotIn               John         In             2
1       NotIn               Alex         In            NULL
1       NotIn               Mike         In            NULL  
2        In                 Mike         NotIn          2
```

And my source table looks like this tbl_Source:

```
 ID Name   Type Cost  
 1  Mike    2   100   
 2  Cole    2   200  
 3  Ken     1   300  
 4  Tara    1   400  
 5  Mike    1   500
 6  Sonya   1   600 
 7  Ann     2   700
 8  Mike    1   800
```

I want to be able to join these two tables and get the following result tbl_Result:

```
RuleID  Name  Type  Cost
  1     Cole   2    200
  1     Ann    2    700  
  2     Mike   1    500  
  2     Mike   1    800
```

If I was writing this query manually my query would look like this:

```
select 1, Name, Type, Cost 
from tbl_Source 
Where Name not in ('John', 'Alex', 'Mike') and Type in (2) 
union all
select 2, Name, Type, Cost
from tbl_Source
where Name in ('Mike') and Type not in (2)
```

In my current setup tbl_Rule has 500 records and tbl_Source has 500k records.

Any advice on this can be achieved is greatly appreciated. Limitations:
No CLR functions, No 2017 features (e.g. String_agg)

Update: DDL statements for the above sample can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9a29f/2/0

Comment: I’m curious, why are you doing this in SQL?

Comment: @MikeDinescu, good question. This is our current setup and there's no way to do it in code. But even if we do it in code it looks like it will be much slower. (As I mentioned, table has 500k records and more columns than in this example)

Comment: In `tbl_Rules`, what's the meaning of NULL in the value columns? Also, can the value columns hold csv like values `1,2` or just a single value?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, just a single value. The reason why we need NULL is because for NameValues we have 3 records and for TypeValue has 1 record. Nulls can be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. I have used `cross join` to check the rules. There may be better ways with dynamic SQL where rules are implemented in `join`

```
declare @tbl_Rules table(
    RuleID int
    , NameOperator varchar(20)
    , NameValues varchar(20)
    , TypeOperator varchar(20)
    , TypeValue int
)
insert into @tbl_Rules
values 
(1, 'NotIn', 'John', 'In', 2)
, (1, 'NotIn', 'Alex', 'In', NULL)
, (1, 'NotIn', 'Mike', 'In', NULL)
, (2, 'In', 'Mike', 'NotIn', 2)

declare @tbl_Source table (
    ID int
    , Name varchar(20)
    , Type int
    , Cost int
)
insert into @tbl_Source
values
(1, 'Mike', 2, 100)
, (2, 'Cole', 2, 200)
, (3, 'Ken', 1, 300) 
, (4, 'Tara', 1, 400)
, (5, 'Mike', 1, 500)
, (6, 'Sonya', 1, 600) 
, (7, 'Ann', 2, 700)
, (8, 'Mike', 1, 800)

;with cte as (
    select
        distinct Ruleid, a.NameOperator, a.TypeOperator
         , NameValues = (
            select
                '!' + b.NameValues
            from
                @tbl_Rules b
            where
                a.RuleID = b.RuleID
                and b.NameValues is not null
            for xml path('')
        ) + '!'
        , TypeValue = (
            select
                concat('!', b.TypeValue)
            from
                @tbl_Rules b
            where
                a.RuleID = b.RuleID
                and b.TypeValue is not null
            for xml path('')
        ) + '!'
    from 
        @tbl_Rules a
)

select
    b.RuleID, a.Name, a.Type, a.Cost
from
    @tbl_Source a
    cross join cte b
where
    1 = case
        when b.NameOperator = 'In' and charindex('!' + a.Name + '!', b.NameValues) > 0 and b.TypeOperator = 'In' and charindex(concat('!', a.Type, '!'), b.TypeValue) > 0 then 1
        when b.NameOperator = 'In' and charindex('!' + a.Name + '!', b.NameValues) > 0 and b.TypeOperator = 'Notin' and charindex(concat('!', a.Type, '!'), b.TypeValue) = 0 then 1
        when b.NameOperator = 'NotIn' and charindex('!' + a.Name + '!', b.NameValues) = 0 and b.TypeOperator = 'In' and charindex(concat('!', a.Type, '!'), b.TypeValue) > 0 then 1
        when b.NameOperator = 'NotIn' and charindex('!' + a.Name + '!', b.NameValues) = 0 and b.TypeOperator = 'NotIn' and charindex(concat('!', a.Type, '!'), b.TypeValue) = 0 then 1
        else 0
    end
```

Output:

```
RuleID   Name   Type   Cost
---------------------------
1        Cole   2      200
1        Ann    2      700
2        Mike   1      500
2        Mike   1      800
```

Comment: Thanks so much it seems to work as expected. I do have one question: In my real scenario I have four filtering parameters, not two. (In my example above I have Name + Type, but in reality I have Name + Type + LastName + ReferenceNumber. So, it looks like I need to write 16 case WHEN statements. Do you have any idea if this can be achieved in an easier manner?

Comment: I don't think that's possible in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT MAX(R_N.RuleID) RuleID,  S.Name, S.Type, S.Cost 
FROM tbl_Source S
    INNER JOIN tbl_Rules R_N ON 
           (R_N.NameValues <> S.Name and R_N.NameOperator = 'NotIn' )
        OR (R_N.NameValues = S.Name and R_N.NameOperator = 'In' )
    INNER JOIN tbl_Rules R_S ON 
           R_S.RuleID = R_N.RuleID AND
           (R_S.TypeValue <> S.Type and R_S.TypeOperator = 'NotIn' )
        OR (R_S.TypeValue = S.Type and R_S.TypeOperator = 'In' )
GROUP BY 
    S.Name, S.Type, S.Cost
HAVING
    MAX(R_N.NameOperator) = MIN(R_N.NameOperator) 
    AND MAX(R_S.TypeOperator) = MIN(R_S.TypeOperator)
```

Result:

```
RuleID      Name                 Type        Cost
----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
1           Ann                  2           700
1           Cole                 2           200
2           Mike                 1           500
2           Mike                 1           800
```